# Failed to validate captcha [browser-error]

Tags: mobile-safari, recaptcha-v3

Why have an issue on Mobile Safari
**Failed to validate captcha [browser-error] error**
n App.ts

```
<GoogleReCaptchaProvider language={language} reCaptchaKey={siteKey}><Submit/></GoogleReCaptchaProvider>
```

and the component

```
<GoogleReCaptcha onVerify={onClick} refreshReCaptcha={refreshReCaptcha} />
```

every

const REFRESH_CAPTHCA_TIME = 90000;

there is a refresh for captcha

web browsers, android all is working, issue is exactly on Mobile Safari